# PivotCaches - Generate an error "created in a later version of Excel"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

This stupid issue is seriously driving me mad, and I haven't found a way to fix this yet...

---

I have **Excel 2010 at work**,  and **Excel 2013 at home**.

I worked **once home and created a few Pivot Tables**, and **discover at work** that error message :

> [image]

So afterwards, I was cautious, I **recreated everything after deleting the Pivot Tables I did at home**. At that point, I was able to use my file and generate the reports.

A month after that, I've got exactly the **same issue with all the Pivot Table (around 50...) on that data source**... So I recreated everything and yet after few minutes AFK, I've got the **same message for everything I just created**...

So, **my guess is that the Pivot Tables I created on 2013 must have upgrade the PivotCache and now every table on that data source use that cache and I can't update any of it**...

> Any idea how to *downgrade* the PivotCache or some workaround or anything?

Because at that point, I'm close to restart all from scratch but I'm kind of missing time to do that...

Comment: I found these two sources on Google, have you seen both already? Basically, it seems really hard to delete pivotcaches, but you could try both of these:
http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot11.html#removedups - clears all data from Pivotcache, might help get rid of the 2013 feature
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/8472-programatically-clear-pivotcache-memory.html - "Per Microsoft: If the PivotTable cache isn't referenced by a PivotTable object, the PivotTable cache is automatically deleted before the workbook is saved."

Comment: Yes I saw them, but basically the implied solution is too get rid of all the Pivot Tables from the Pivot Cache, then save, and restart from scratch for these Tables. I've done that today and yet it seems that the issue isn't solved... And I check, I don't have any duplicate caches... :/
But many many thanks for looking around and for your input! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry you are so stuck at the moment :(

Comment: Another three years later and people are still stuck on this problem (and a hundred google searches later)